# How can I install laravel 4 with the minimal components I need?

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Is there a way to configure composer to install the Laravel 4 framework with only the most minimal of components needed to drive a basic (mostly empty) application? Just enough to cough out "hello world" from a controller.

Basically I want to be able to decide what components to use for my needs as I go.

I want to be able to choose an alternate view/template system if I want, or form validation, database, etc.

Mostly I'm just looking for a way to specify a streamlined set of dependencies in composer, so my package will only install with the components it needs and not a bunch of default libraries it will never use.

Comment: I'd recommend you look into Silex to start your application, and then pull in whatever Laravel libraries you need/want. Silex will use the same general routing mechanisms (Both frameworks use Symfony HTTP components under the hood). Silex is built to start light and let you add in whatever dependencies you want - you can add whatever Illuminate (or other) packages you may want to try out. Laravel isn't built around the assumption that you will put together an app piecemeal - you may find yourself wasting a lot of time fighting against that.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of asking composer for `laravel/framework`, only require `illuminate/routing`. This will pull in everything you need for the routing.

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/routing": "4.1.*@dev"
    }
}
```

Then, as you go along, you can require whatever [other illuminate packages](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/) you need.

Comment: The skeleton application `laravel/laravel` that most people use to start a laravel project expects more than the routing library to exist (I'm guessing). This method **might** require the OP to code their own bootstrapping process. Not that there's anything wrong with that, other than duplicating efforts.

Answer (score -4):

I dont think you can, as soon as you require laravel/framework it pulls in everything it needs. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/composer.json

Laravel 4 is pretty light anyway, the packages it pulls in are quite small

Comment: Yeah, 20 megs by default, of which 5 only for creating "fake text" (faker) in many languages. On the bright side most of this is superfluous stuff and it should be possible to reduce the size to like 10 megs, I estimate. But I will be happy when my Laravel install is 50K or 100K. That'll probably contain all the features I need, and then I know that I could actually read and understand the whole source. Does anyone care about that anymore?